# how to fix syntastic javascript warnings: 'X is not defined'?

Tags: javascript, vim, syntastic

I am using vim with syntastic on a javascript (cordova) project, but I am getting a lot of warnings as can be seen below:

[image]

I consider to be a javascript noob, so I'm a little concerned that my code is not to a good standard.

How can I fix these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the solution was to add the following as a header:

```
/* global SettingsManager, $  */
```

I.e.

```
/* global SettingsManager, $  */

(function() {
    "use strict";

    var settingsManager = SettingsManager.getInstance();

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#budgetSummaryList", function(e) {
    ...
```